# AWS send consecutive HTTP requests to the same load balancing target

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I am a beginner in using AWS elastic load balancer (ELB). Let's say I have written a web service that contains three endpoints:

```
POST /example
PATCH /example/{id}
DELETE /example/{id}
```

If a user sends a http request through the load balancer, it will be routed to instance A. **What I want to achieve, is to route any subsequent http request to the same instance A.**

So if I make a POST request and get an id, that id is only valid in the memory space of instance A. When ELB routes to instance B, that id is invalid and PATCH and DELETE requests fail.

Is this something ELB can achieve by itself? or there needs to be some sort of a software middleware involved?

Comment: of course right after I typed this, I found https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html
will leave the question open for a while to see if someone has a better solution.

Comment: Not sure what you'd consider a "better" solution.  It would be *better* if your application did not require that subsequent requests go to the same back-end, because you could lose a back-end at any time.  The fact that it does seems to imply that your application has design weaknesses.  ALB also supports stickiness:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the API behind the service is using ffmpeg in the cloud to do some sort of transcoding. So when you POST, it spawns an instance of ffmpeg and with subsequent calls you can control the spawned instance. Unfortunately there is no way around it. Sticky sessions seems the way to go. Thanks!